# Git status неверно отображает статус

Tags: git

Привет! Использую git, хранилище - bitbucket.

Отправляя коммит, данные в хранилище обновляются. Но вот если на другом компьютере проверяешь версию git status, пишет что все ок и ничего не обновлено.

Подскажите что делать..

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` на другой машине сделали?

Comment: @deterok нет, извиняюсь за вопрос: а что она делает?

Comment: fetch - этого не всегда достаточно.

Суть в том, что если сделать push на одной машине, то другие об этом не узнают, пока не утянут с сервера свежую версию. Говоря другими словами, git status  в сеть не лезет. 

Но лучше делать git pull - он делает git fetch (утягивает все изменения с удаленного репозитория) а потом делает merge.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вы ожидаете сообщений такого вида:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

`git status` показывает разницу между вашей локальной веткой и слепком [удалённой ветки](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) на вашей машине. В моём случае это `master` (у меня) и `origin/master` (зеркало `master` с сервера `origin`).

Чтобы увидеть это сообщение, просто запушить новые коммиты в удалённый репозиторий *недостаточно*. Git *распределённый*, состояние удалённого репозитория не имеет никакого отношения к состоянию локального. Для работы с удалёнными репозиториями имеется отдельный набор команд, `status` в них не входит.

**Можно сделать `git fetch`.** Он затянет с сервера те коммиты, которых у вас не хватает, но больше ничего с ними делать не будет. Они появятся в `origin/master`, и `git status` покажет их наличие.

...это при условии, что локальная ветка `master` следует (tracks) за `origin/master`. Скорее всего, следит. Слежение могло начаться:

- после [клонирования](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone): Git делает новую ветку, следящую за [активной на сервере](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700598/what-is-the-cloned-repositorys-currently-active-branch)
- после пуша с явным указанием слежения `git push --set-upstream origin master`
- явно `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`
- в других случаях

Answer (score 0):

```
git status
```

отображает состояние на локальной машине, которая не факт, что синхронизированна с общим репозиторием. 
Различия в результате данной команды говорят не о том что команда "сломалась" на одной из машин, а о том что репозитории рассинхронизированны.